# Create a basic Model using an Eloquent Model to render in View

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have created a ViewModel which has two Eloquent models as properties. I want to use the ViewModel with two non-Eloquent models with the same properties as the table / eloquent models used to populate mock-up objects as properties of the ViewModel after instantiation.

The idea is that I can create this ViewModel **"on-the-fly"** and its properties aka Eloquent Models.

Is and How is it possible to create models that use the pre-defined eloquent models in my project/package without actually having any relationship to the table besides it's schema::table properties? The ImageItem and PageInfo Models are Eloquent models and are used as directed, but I want to use their class templates to create dynamic objects that are not relational to the database. I'm going to scrap these objects out once the page is rendered they're gone.

The problem I am having is the View doesnt identify the object in its current state

Here is an example of my code:

**Basic view model that gets passed to view as compact('page')**

```
class LandingPageViewModel extends Model
{
     ImageItem $img;
     PageInfo $info;

   __construct($img = NULL, $info = NULL){
             if(!$img && !$info){
                $img = ImageItem::where("key","=","notfound").first();
                $info = PageInfo::where("key","=","notfound").first();
             }
             else{
                  $this->img = $img;
                  $this->info = $info;
            }
    }
}
```

**This is where is gets a little blurry for me..These are two Eloquent models but in this case I only want to use them as templates. Meaning I wil not save these objects to the database. Think of them as child ViewModels at this point similar to how ASP.NET MVC works**

```
public ImageItem(){
   __construct(){
         parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
}

public PageInfo(){
   __construct(){
         parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

}
```

**In the controller let's say I have a function that creates an error page based off error codes and I return the LandingPageViewModel to the shared view that contains non-eloquent objects**

```
function getErrorPage($params){

//do some looping through params and assign value to properties based on key/column names of eloquent models stored in my db 
$mockImage = new ImageItem();
$mockInfo = new PageInfo();
foreach($params as $k => $v){
   if($k == `***Schema::getColumnListing('image_item')***`){ //image_item is table name
       $mockImage->column['name'] = $v;
    }
 etc....
 $page = new LandingViewModel($mockImage,$mockInfo);
return view("landing.index",compact('page');
}
```

Comment: What is your question?